# In Windows, can you programmatically (C++) detect which DLLs have been loaded by other running programs?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I hope this is not a no-brainer question, but in Windows, is it possible to programmatically (C++) check which DLLs have been loaded by other concurrently running programs?

I know that the `GetModuleHandle` functions can be used to detect DLLs that have been loaded by the current program, but it does not work across program boundaries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Enumerate all DLLs in the system and those loaded by you, and perform a minus?

Comment: Unless you are writing TaskManager/ProcessExplorer kind of application, I wonder why do you need such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toolhlp32.dll does that. See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686840(v=VS.85).aspx

The API you ultimately want is Module32First/Next.

Answer (score 1):

The PSAPI ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx ) also provides a few functions to do spelunking through the system process and modules list, it can also pick up some of the modules that toolhlp32 might miss for various reasons (such as being manually hidden). It also works on x64 processes too iirc